# Android fragment layout finished inflating

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, fragment

I want to add some graphics to a layout programmatically. I want to position the graphics dynamically based on the position of other graphical elements in the `xml layout file`.

The positions of the graphics in the layout are all 0 if I try to access them in `onCreateView` or in `onViewCreated`. This is probably because the layout hasn't finished inflating.

Where can I hook up my code to be sure that the layout of the fragment has completed inflating?

At the moment I have solved it using the `viewTreeObserver`(see code below), but is this really the smartest way?

I am working inside a fragment.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfrg, container, false);
        mMainLayoutCanvas = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.myfrg_mainlayout);
        mMainLayoutCanvas.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                initializeUI();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: The way u did it, is the right way to do it, since waiting for onActivityCreated() like @RubenWeerts says takes more time.

Comment: @Daniel How does it take more time?

Comment: @MaciejGórski I think he means that this is the right place to do it because the onCreateView is meant to draw the fragment's user interface. The onActivityCreated should handle retrieving states etc. not layouts (user interface). It's takes more time because onCreateView is called before onActivityCreated. Reference link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

onCreateView inflates the `Fragment`'s layout. You only can find the views after onCreateView has returned. 
I'd go for `onActivityCreated()` method to find the views and then update/position them.

There might be a totally different solution tough, I just started on Android

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to set a preDraw listener on the inflated fragment layout, this will give you a callback when all of the dimensions have been resolved.

```
layout = inflater.inflate(...);
ViewTreeObserver obs = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
obs.addOnPreDrawListener(mListener);
```

Don't forget to remove the listener when you are finished doing your operations or this will result in an endless loop since any layout operations will cause this to be called again.

```
obs.removePreDrawListener(mListener);
```